# Mac doesn't compile, Windows and Linux does - Boost ASIO?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, boost-asio

I have a boost socket implementation and it works perfectly on Windows & Linux, but on mac the same code gets a bunch of compilation errors such as.

```
src/modules/socket/ssl_tcp_socket_binding.cpp: In constructor 
'ti::SecureTCPSocket::SecureTCPSocket(tide::Host*, ti::TCPSocketBinding*)':
src/modules/socket/ssl_tcp_socket_binding.cpp:27: error: class 'ti::SecureTCPSocket' does not have any field named 'Socket'
src/modules/socket/ssl_tcp_socket_binding.cpp:29: error: no matching function for call to 'ti::Socket<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&> >::Socket()'
```

Constructor

```
SecureTCPSocket::SecureTCPSocket(Host *host, TCPSocketBinding * tcp_socket_binding)
        : Socket(host, string("Socket.SecureTCPSocket")),
```

Header

```
class SecureTCPSocket
        : public Socket<boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&> >
    {
```

I don't understand why this is an issue on Mac's but perfectly fine on Linux & Windows?

Any idea as to what I may be doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mentioning a class template different than the one you are currently implementing, you have to specify the template arguments. Unless it is a copy&paste error, you need to use

```
SecureTCPSocket::SecureTCPSocket(Host *host, TCPSocketBinding * tcp_socket_binding)
    : Socket<boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&> >(host,
                                                      string("Socket.SecureTCPSocket")),
      ...
```

In fact, the error message indicates that need: it states that it doesn't know what `Socket` is and continues to state that there is no matching constructor for the instantiation `Socket<boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&> >` (well, a more expanded version thereof).

The question in this case actually isn't why the compiler used on Mac (clang?) doesn't compile the code but rather why the compilers used on Windows and Linux do compile the code!

Comment: If I do that I get a giant error complaining about `NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition. ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386` which makes even less sense then this error +_+

Comment: @Steven: I'd say this error makes perfect sense and probably points towards another issue where the other compilers are more sloppy! This time it points out that a function which needs to be defined (e.g., a template instantiation) happens not to be instantiated. It also implies that the compile-time error, indeed, got resolved but linking fails. This is, at least, progress!